# SQL Server Job History Disappears After 5 Days

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-agent, maintenance-plans

I feel like this is a silly question but for the life of me, I can't track down what is going on. I have just taken over administration of several servers and on all of them, the job history is being retained for only 5 days. There is a cleanup maintenance plan but it's set for 5 week retention.

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_purge_history is being run daily however, the History Retention Days is set to 0 so my understanding is that it's not doing anything anyway.

There has to be something really simple I'm missing here. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That job has to do with policy-based management, not SQL Server Agent jobs in general. In Object Explorer right-click SQL Server Agent and select Properties, then move to the History tab. What does it say here:

[image]

You can adjust those settings so that it keeps more rows overall, more rows per job, and keeps history longer. I am guessing either you have a lot of jobs on this server or these settings have been changed.

Comment: I love you Aaron (in a manly kind of way!) You are right...the numbers were set low and we have tons of jobs....problem solved!

Comment: Whoa, easy now...